# CSS Buttons not working in IE, but does in FF

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I've been looking on the internet for solutions as to why IE7 isn't opening links correctly for example

```
    <a href="http://www.google.com"><button class="class1">Google</button></a>
```

Does IE7 not like having    ?

I hear I should use jquery for this? But no one linked to any article.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the W3C's specifications on [anchor (`<a>`) tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/struct/links.html#h-12.2) and [`<button>` tags](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.5), you should be able to do that fine, but [according to a quick Google search](http://www.google.com/search?ie=UTF-8&sourceid=navclient&gfns=1&q=button+tag+inside+a+tag), you can't and/or shouldn't do it, and it doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

[This article](http://www.expertsguide.info/2010/07/button-tag-inside-anchor-not-working-in-i/) actually recommends adding Javascript, so the link can be opened in IE also:

```
<a href="http://www.expertsguide.info/"><button type="button" onclick="window.location('http://www.expertsguide.info/')">Click Me to go to Experts Guide</button></a>
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the solution I used, except for some reason it has to be window.location.href... weird isn't it?

Answer (score 1):

Although you can, you shouldn't have a button (`<button>`) inside anchor (`<a>`).

Add an event handler to the button like this:

```
<input type="button" value="Google" onClick="javascript:location.href = 'http://google.com';" />
```

Note: you should considered not doing this, for a variety of reasons. Bottom line you can (and should) style your `<a>` element to look like a button.

Comment: According to the W3C, you can have form elements (which includes `<button>`) inside of an anchor tag.

Comment: @Nightfirecat You're right. It can be done, but it shouldn't be done. Edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off not using a button inside a hyperlink.

Style the hyperlink to look like a button.

Try these

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/css3-buttons-10-awesome-ready-to-use-solutions-all-related-tutorials-you-need/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('.class1').click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).parent().attr('href');
      return false;
   }

});

</script>
```

Or simply remove the button tag and use this:

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

   $('a').click(function() {
      window.location = $(this).attr('href');
      return false;
   }

});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be JavaScript independent (so that it also works on browsers with JS disabled, in contrary to many other answers here), I'd suggest to just wrap it in a `<form>` the usual way and make it a `<button type="submit">` (or `<input type="submit">`) instead.

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com">
  <button type="submit" class="class1">Google</button>
</form>
```

or

```html
<form action="http://www.google.com">
  <input type="submit" value="Google" class="class1" />
</form>
```